# Assets URL not working because of load balancer in to Yii

Tags: php, yii, load-balancing, assets

I am working on Yii 1.2 frameworks project.
I have create a assets URL using below code.

```
$this->_assetsUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('aessessment.assets'));
```

where **aessessment** is the module name.

For fetching assets data I have used below code.

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents($this->module->assetsUrl . '/pdfcss/style.css');
```

**This code is work perfectly in my local system and also on my development server.**

For Production I have manage two server named like **study1** and **study2** usign load balancer.

So If user opens URL study.mywebsite.com then load balancer send request to study1 or study2 server.

**I got the problem here. file_get_contents gives me a empty result here.**

I have tried to insert css file into view using assets URL using below code.

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->module->assetsUrl; ?>/gcicss/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It is also not working on study.mysite.com URL.

If I tried with **study1.mysite.com** or **study2.mysite.com** URL then all the things working fine.

but I can't get success on URL **study.mysite.com**.

I have search multiple answers online but not getting success.

**Any help will be highly appreciate.**

**Thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 1):

It's usual problem while assets generates by backend server and puts into its file system.

The simplest way to fix it - to change webserver settings for assets folder on study.mysite.com. It should try to find concrete assets file on first server and when in case of fail try to find this file on second server. But this approach bad scales for 3, 4, 5 and so on servers.

It will be better to publish assets from both server to one place which will available for webserver of study.mysite.com.

I draw a picture with this simplect schema:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have also tried this idea to generates in one common virtual directory.

I had changed assets mangager base path into config file as like this.
 'assetManager'=>array('basePath'=>realpath('\\SERVER IP\FOLDER PATH\ASSETS FOLDER'),'baseUrl'=>'/resources_nt/assets/'),
 but it was not working. Can you guide me more about this?

Comment: I don't surely remember, but standard assetManager can't save file on other server. Once upon a time I inherited my own assetManager class  from standard Yii class and rewrite publish method. My method upload files on our small CDN from which we distributed static files.